# Identify click event from common html element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have one bootstrap card and on clicking on it I am redirecting the user to another page. Now I am adding some description on the same card with some character limit. Once the character limit exceeds, I am showing read more... I want when user clicks on read more, it will open a modal where they can read the full description and can also edit it if they want. The problem I am facing right now is, even when clicking on read more, its considering it a click on the card and redirecting the user to another page instead of opening the modal. How would I handle this case.

My HTML Code

```
<div id="someid" class="card tile-card estimate">
   <div class="card-header p-3 pt-2">
      <div class="icon icon-lg icon-shape bg-gradient-dark shadow-dark text-center border-radius-xl mt-n4 position-absolute">
         <i class="fa fa-icon fa-solid fa-dollar-sign opacity-10"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="text-end pt-1">
         <p class="text-sm mb-0 tile-title-p">Some Text</p>
         <p class="text-xs mb-0 tile-subtitle-p">Some More Text</p>
         <p class="text-xs mb-0 tile-subtitle-p" style="font-weight:bold;">@EFITStatus</p>
         <p class="text-xs mb-0 tile-subtitle-p fifty-chars" style="text-align: left;" title="Description">
            Some fixed character description
         </p>
         <div style="display:inline-flex">
            <span class="tile-number-title"></span>
            <h3 class="tile-number mb-0"></h3>
         </div>
         <div style="display:inline-flex">
            <span class="tile-number-title"></span>
            <h3 class="tile-number mb-0"></h3>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card-footer p-3">
      <p class="tile-subtitle-p tile-subtitle-footer mb-0">Footer</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

On the first div element I have a class of name estimate on which I am calling an click event. when trying to call the click event of .readmore class, its still calling the first click event.

Below are my two independent functions.

For redirecting the user to another page

```
$('.estimate').on('click', function (item) {
                    var eFITID = $(this).data('efitid');
                    window.location.href = "my path";
            });
```

Below function is for character limit and opening the modal when user clicks on read more link

```
$(function () {
            var maxL = 20;
            $('.fifty-chars').each(function () {
                var text = $(this).text().trim();
                if (text.length > maxL) {
                    var begin = text.substr(0, maxL),
                        end = text.substr(maxL);

                    $(this).html(begin)
                        .append($('<a class="readmore"/>').html('read more...'))
                }
            });
            $(document).on('click', '.readmore', function (e) {
                $(this).next('.hiddenText').slideToggle(400);
                $("#modalEditDescription").modal('show');
            });
        });
```

How would handle this case. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have to make sure the "read more" gets triggered before the card click. Then you can stop the event from continuing the event chain. See https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: Thanks for ur response @Kokodoko. How would I make sure that my read more triggered before the card click ?

Comment: @Yogi- I am using version 4 of bootstrap

Comment: @Kokodoko - I have gone through the link which u mentioned and there it says -- Note that this will not prevent other handlers on the same element from running. And this is exactly the case here. Could you please suggest any other alternative way.

Comment: Just have a click listener for the entire card and check if the target is the read-more, if not do what you were intending to do.

Comment: You don't need event delegation on .readmore.   You append the .readmore elements, *then* add the event handler, so they exist at the time the event wire-up code runs.

Comment: You can also switch `html.append(more)` to `more.appendTo(html).on("click"..` to keep the reference of the newly added `readmore` and add the event handler directly.

Comment: @Yogi -- I have modified my question with more details and also added the HTML code. I hope I have explained it in a better way now.

Comment: @Yogi -- Here is my fiddle link -- https://jsfiddle.net/TechBrania/rntvq04e/   with the problem. If you click inside the card or on read more it will redirect you to google page.

Comment: The cause is the target of the events.   Your "card" event target is `$('.estimate')` while your readmore target is `document` (which is obviously higher)

Comment: @freedomn-m - Yeah, how would I handle could you please help

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '.readmore', function...` -> `$('.readmore').on('click', function...`  Also, because you're (semantically incorrectly) using an `<a>` (instead of a styled button) you need to cancel the `<a>` default action.  https://jsfiddle.net/9kf7enb1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255425/discussion-between-obraine-and-freedomn-m).

Comment: As @freedomn-m mentioned in his fiddle, I have tried the same and replaced my anchor tag with a button, it resolved my issue and I am able to perform both the separate operations independently.

Comment: @Yogi - Thanks to you sir as well.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix that, as @Freedomn suggested, I removed the anchor tag and changed $(document).on('click', '.readmore', function... to $('.readmore').on('click', function....
Below is the working code.

```
$(function() {
    var maxL = 20;
    $('.fifty-chars').each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().trim();
        if (text.length > maxL) {
            var begin = text.substr(0, maxL),
                end = text.substr(maxL);

            $(this).html(begin).append('...')
                .append($('<i class="fa fa-edit readmore ml-2" style="color:#f84018"></i >'))

        } else {
            $(this).html(begin)
                .append($('<i class="fa fa-edit readmore ml-2" style="color:#f84018"></i >'))
        }
    });
    $('.readmore').on('click', function(e) {
        $("#modalEditDescription").modal('show');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer to close the question

Answer (score 0):

To handle the issue where clicking on "read more" is also triggering the card click event and redirecting the user, you can stop the propagation of the click event on the "read more" link. This prevents the click event from bubbling up to the card's click event handler. You can achieve this by using the e.stopPropagation() function.

Here's the modified code:

```
$('.estimate').on('click', function (item) {
    var eFITID = $(this).data('efitid');
    window.location.href = "my path";
});

// Function for character limit and opening the modal when user clicks on read more link
$(function () {
    var maxL = 20;
    $('.fifty-chars').each(function () {
        var text = $(this).text().trim();
        if (text.length > maxL) {
            var begin = text.substr(0, maxL),
                end = text.substr(maxL);

            $(this).html(begin)
                .append($('<a class="readmore"/>').html('read more...'))
                .append($('<div class="hiddenText"/>').text(end).hide()); // Add hidden text
        }
    });

    // Click event handler for "read more" link
    $(document).on('click', '.readmore', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // Stop the click event from propagating to the card
        $(this).next('.hiddenText').slideToggle(400);
        $("#modalEditDescription").modal('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you create this answer with [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)?

Comment: "*Stop the click event from propagating to the card*" - you should look at the click event target...  not sure "document" is going to propagate *up* to anything...

Comment: @Bradley Duncan Junior - I have tried that also but it didn't work. It was still redirecting the user. BTY thanks for the support.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).